# Ansible playbook: Value of registered variable after multiple runs of same task over different host machines in same group

Tags: ansible, devops

My `/etc/ansible/hosts` file has 3 machines:

```
[local]
172.17.0.1
172.17.0.2
172.17.0.3
```

My playbook is like:

```
name: test
shell: systemctl status httpd
register: httpdstatus
```

If let's say httpd is running on 172.17.0.1 and 172.17.0.2 and not on 172.17.0.3, what will be the final value of httpdstatus.rc?

Can I use individual result code values of httpdstatus.

I basically want to install something on a 4th server which is in a different group, if httpd is installed on any of 172.17.0.1, 172.17.0.2 or 172.17.0.3.

Like below logic:

```
If {
    (httpdstatus.rc for server 1) or
    (httpdstatus.rc for server 2) or
    (httpdstatus.rc for server 3)==1
}
```

then install the package on the 4th machine.
How do I do this in Ansible?

Comment: Maybe you can get more attention to this on Devops: devops.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> If let's say httpd is running on 172.17.0.1 and 172.17.0.2 and not on
>   172.17.0.3, what will be the final value of httpdstatus.rc?

As you are iterating through the list of `httpd` servers, the result of the current item will be placed in the `register` variable.

Refer [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop) official documentation to know the behavior of register variable in a loop.

> Can I use individual result code values of httpdstatus.

Yes, you can use individual result code.

> I basically want to install something on a 4th server which is in a
>   different group, if httpd is installed on any of 172.17.0.1,
>   172.17.0.2 or 172.17.0.3.

Yes, you can do that using include action handlers having ansible 2.0 versions and above. You can write below handler in your playbook to action this.

```
handlers:
    - name: install httpd
      yum: name=httpd
      service: name=httpd state=started
```

In your tasks, you can notify the above handler if you see failures in tasks.

```
- name: test
  service: systemctl status httpd
  register: httpdstatus
  when: httpdstatus.rc==1
  notify: "install httpd"
```

Hope this helps!